# TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Plus driver para Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I am looking for a driver for the TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Plus, on Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel version 4.15.0-72-generic).

I already tried different drivers, none of them worked.

https://www.tp-link.com/br/home-networking/adapter/archer-t2u-plus/

[click to see lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbMAp.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text from a terminal, paste it to the question and format it using `{}` icon above. We can't copy text from your screenshot. Was the adapter inserted when you ran `lsusb`? It looks like it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since it uses the Realtek 8814 chipset you should be able to get it working like this.

Installation on Ubuntu 20.04 (since you run a newer kernel this should work )/(or Linux Mint 20.2 (off-topic)):

Open the terminal and execute the following commands :

1. Update the package information :

`sudo apt update`

2. Install dkms and git :

`sudo apt install dkms git`

3. Install Build Dependencies :

`sudo apt install build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

4. Download the Driver files using git :

`git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git`

5. Navigate to the Downloaded directory :

`cd rtl8812au`

6. Install the Driver

`sudo make dkms_install`

if the installation is aborted , execute this command `sudo dkms remove 8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 --all` , if errors pop up `Usage: remove / --all`

Source:
https://github.com/nlkguy/archer-t2u-plus-linux